# Which wire is best for solenoids

Tags: electromagnetism, radio, coil

I am not an engineer but I want to make a small radio circuit. Which wire would be good for its coil.

Comment: Which coil in the invisible circuit are you talking about?

Comment: You ask about wire for a solenoid but then mention a "radio circuit" which would suggest that the coils isn't a solenoid (electro-magnet) but a coil or inductor. I suggest that you show the schematic of that "radio circuit" and also explain what you want to do with this.

Comment: Well, solenoids and inductors are the same thing. The difference is their purpose.

Comment: @user253751 And a consequence of that difference is that their construction is different, so that something designed as a good solenoid is usually a poor RF inductor and vice versa.

Comment: The wire should be **insulated** wire. usually termed as **enamelled copper wire** or similar. If the coil is wound on a solid core, the wire can be thin. If it is not, then it needs to hold its own shape. Then you have to use thicker wire. The thickness also depends on the current that is expected to flow through the coil.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please add more details to your question using the small [edit] button below your question. The details can include things like frequency of operation, maximum current expected to flow, material of the core of the coil, inductance required etc. If you have a reference circuit for the radio, please add a figure of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use magnet wire. That is copper wire that is insulated with a thin but tough varnish coating. The coating must be scraped or sanded off wherever you need to make a connection. That may be particularly tedious for a coil that needs to have provisions for a contact that slides along the coil to select a connection point on any turn of the coil. It may be possible to make such a coil with bare copper wire, but that requires very careful winding to prevent any turn from touching the ones next to it. That would be a very tedious alternative.

Note that magnet wire is widely available as "magnet wire." It may be described as "enameled wire" also, but that older term seems to be less common.